# Why is my integer viewed by python as a complex number?

Tags: python

I just started a course in Python and trying this code:

```
import math

c = int(input('Enter number: '))

a = 1

counter = 0

while counter != 2:
    a = a + 1
    b = round((c-(a**3))**(1/3.0))

    if a < b and a**3 + b**3 == c:
        counter = counter + 1
        print(a,b)
```

My problem is that python cant round the 'b' since it is viewed as a complex number...

The program is supposed to find two sets of a & b that satisfie a^3+b^3=c, any feed back on my code is appreciated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Please explain why you think ```b``` is complex and post any Traceback.

Comment: cube roots aren't really done well since 1/3 is a rounded of float and wont exactly give you the cube root, which means it may return a complex number (ie, a number with an imaginary part)

Comment: @wwii, I can reproduce `TypeError: type complex doesn't define __round__ method`

Comment: define: "two smallest cubes" please

Comment: Two smallest cubes as in the smallest a and b that satisfies a^3+b^3=c

Answer (score 1):

Basically, raising a negative number to a fractional power always yields a complex number. For example, sqrt(-1) (which is (-1)**(1/2)), is clearly complex.

So, if you try to raise -8 to the 1/3th power, you'll get a complex number. For example:

```
a = (-8)**(1/3)
print(a)
print(a**3)
```

Will print

```
(1.0000000000000002+1.7320508075688772j)
(-8+3.1086244689504383e-15j)
```

That gives back -8 when raised to the 3rd power, give or take some rounding.

This rounding is the real issue here. You could well say that -8 to the power 1/3 is -2, as -2 to the 3rd power is -8. However - and this is the crux - that only works if the power is actually 1/3. In a floating point number it will actually be 0.33333 (with some more threes), which is not exactly the same. Hence the exponentiation is done with complex numbers.

You'll either have to work with complex numbers, or rewrite your maths to not use fractional powers of negative numbers.

Answer (score -3):

You need to guard your computation against a^3 being larger than c; that's what returns a complex number.  Make sure that you move the increment of `a`, so that the `while` uses that same value.  Perhaps

```
while counter != 2 and c >= a**3:
    b = round((c-(a**3))**(1/3.0))

    if a < b and a**3 + b**3 == c:
        counter = counter + 1
        print(a,b)

    a = a + 1
```

Output with c = 1729, the Ramanujan-Hardy number:

```
1 12
9 10
```

Also, why are you waiting for *two* solutions?  "counter" puzzles me ... you could use a Boolean flag if you need only one solution.

Comment: Did you try this? In other words this does not work.

Comment: My apology.  I am not able to try it, as the error does not reproduce in my installation of Python 2.7.  What values of a and c give the problem, then?  You might try printing them out before rounding.

Comment: Sorry, my program is suposed to find two different sets of a & b integers that satisfies a^3+b^3=c